# JavaFX usage of "in jar" images in css

Tags: java, css, user-interface, styles, javafx-2

I am trying to add background image to some pane in my javafx application, the image is located inside the package resources.img and the css is located inside the package resources.css

if i setting the background image programmatically like suggested in this thread: 
[Setting background image by javafx code (not css)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851200/setting-background-image-by-javafx-code-not-css)

it works fine but i would like to know if i can set the background image from the css file itself.

i tried

```
-fx-background-image: url("@../img/myImage.png");
```

but then the css interpreter didn't find the image file.
is it possible to do what i want via css?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaFX CSS parser has a limitation like

> @-keyword statements are ignored.

described in "Limitations" section of CSS Reference Guide. It may be the cause of your problem though didn't confirm myself. Can you   try like this: `-fx-background-image: url("../img/myImage.png");`
or `-fx-background-image: url("resources/img/myImage.png");`.

Comment: -fx-background-image: url("../img/myImage.png"); did the trick! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps someone it will be useful.
If you specified: `-fx-background-image: url("resources/img/myImage.png");`.
It's possible that standalone `.jar` file will successfully load the image while IDE(like Eclipse) won't. It because IDE alters path and will search something like: `C:/My_project/resources/css/resources/img/myImage.png`.
It means `root` for specified path will folder with css file instead of `.jar` package